# Roots, Formal Derivatives, and Polynomials Over a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

Here is theorem 6.10 part (iii) in Hungerford's algebra book:

> If $D$ is a field, $f$ is irreducible in $D[x]$ and $E \supseteq D$ contains a root of $f$, then $f$ has no multiple roots in $E$ if and only if $f' \neq 0$.

Here is the part of the proof I don't understand:

> If $f$ is irreducible and $f' \neq 0$, then $f$ and $f'$ are relatively prime since $\deg f' < \deg f$.

I am having trouble justifying that $f$ and $f'$ are relatively prime. Suppose that $d$ is a divisor of both $f$ and $f'$. Then $f=hd$ and $f'=kd$. Since $f$ is irreducible, either $h$ or $d$ is a unit. If $h$ is a unit, then $fh^{-1}=d$ and therefore $f' = f'=kfh^{-1}$ which implies

$$\deg f' = \deg(kfh^{-1}) = \deg(k) + \deg(f) + \deg(h^{-1}) = \deg(k) + \deg(f) \ge \deg (f),$$

which is a contradiction. Hence $d$ must be a unit and therefore $d \in D-\{0\}$, since $d$ is a field...But I don't know how to conclude that $d=1$...At this point I am unsure how to proceed. I could use some help.

Comment: You seem to be confused on how divisibility works in a field: in a field *any* unit is divisible by any other, for example, a unit $u$ divides $1$, since $1 = u\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$. Remember, in a UFD, factoring is only unique up to a unit. For example, in $\Bbb Z$, we have $6 = 2\cdot 3 = (-1)(-2)(3) = (-1)(-1)(2\cdot 3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you definitely don't need to prove that $d=1$.  That's not the definition of what it means for $f$ and $f'$ to be relatively prime.  To prove $1$ is the greatest common factor of $f$ and $f'$, you need to prove that $1$ is *divisible* by any common factor $d$ of $f$ and $f'$.  This just means that you need to show $d$ is a unit, as you have already done.

Comment: Not according to Hungerford: "If $R$ has an identity and $a_1,...,a_n$ have $1_R$ as their greatest common divisor, then $a_1,...,a_n)$ are said to be relatively prime.

Comment: What is Hungerford's definition of "greatest common divisor"?

Comment: @user193319: How is the "greatest common divisor" defined in your book? Chances are, it is either only defined up to multiplication by a nonzero scalar (in which case, $d \in D - \left\{0\right\}$ is "equivalent" to $d = 1$), or it is required to be monic in its definition.

Comment: Definition: Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of a commutative ring $R$. An element $d \in R$ is a greatest common divisor of $X$ provided: (i) $d \mid a$ for all $a \in X$; (ii) $c \mid a$ for all $a \in X$ implies $c \mid d$.